# Why does a working shell script stop executing when executed from shelljs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell

I've been working on a shell script to automatically set up the directory system for a basic web document, as an attempt to keep my projects a bit more consistently organized.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -e $1 ]; then
    echo $1 'already exists!'
    exit
else
    echo 'Generating' $1 '. . .' 
    mkdir $1
    cd $1
    mkdir 'html'
    mkdir 'scripts'
    touch 'scripts/app.js'
    mkdir 'style'
    touch 'style/style.css'
    touch 'index.html'
    echo '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>' > 'index.html'
    read -p 'Do you want a git repo? [Y/N]' response
    if [ $response = 'Y' ] || [ $response = 'y' ]; then
        echo 'Generating git repo . . .'
        git init
    fi
fi

if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
    read -p 'Do you want a package.json? [Y/N] ' response
    if [ $response = 'Y' ] || [ $response = 'y' ]; then
        npm init
    fi
else 
    npm init
    shift
    echo 'installing' $*
    npm install $*
    touch '.gitignore'
    echo '/node_modules' > '.gitignore'
fi

echo 'Your web app has been generated!'
echo 'You can find it at'
pwd

read -p 'Would you like to push your first commit now? [Y/N]'

if [ $response = 'Y' ] || [ $response = 'y' ]; then
    git add .
    git commit -m 'initial commit'
    read -p 'Please enter the url to your git (.git):' url
    git remote add origin $url
    git push -u origin master
fi

read -p 'Would you like to open VSCode? [Y/N] ' response
if [ $response = 'Y' ] || [ $response = 'y' ]; then
    code .
fi

read -p 'Would you like to start live-server? [Y/N] ' response
if [ $response = 'Y' ] || [ $response = 'y' ]; then
    live-server
fi

exit
```

The shell script works when I run it natively (ex: `./webapp.sh myapp lodash`).  It will create the directories and, if prompted, initialize a git repo and install dependencies, open VSCode and launch live-server.  That's great and all.

But then I had a thought, if I refined this, maybe others would want to use it and it might be useful as an NPM package (granted, it's nowhere near ready for an NPM publication).  Instead of rewriting the whole thing in Node, I decided to just use `shelljs`:

```
const shelljs = require('shelljs');

const args = process.argv.slice(2).reduce((accum, current)=> {
    return accum + current + ' ';
}, ' ').trim();

shelljs.exec(`./webapp.sh ${args}`);
```

Using Javascript it would be called `node ./webapp.js myapp lodash express` (as an example.)  In this case, shelljs should execute `./webapp.sh myapp lodash express` (where myapp is the name of the app and any following arguments are libraries to be installed).  But what happens is after setting up the initial directories and echoing `Generating myap ...` it just hangs.  It doesn't run the `read -p 'Do you want a git repo'` line.

Is this a problem with my version of bash (3.2) not matching that of Shelljs maybe?  I mean, it works fine if I just run it as a shell script, but if I try to run it through shelljs, it hangs.  Is there a solution to this?  Why would it hang on that `read -p . . .` line only if called through shelljs?

The repo is here: https://github.com/jckuhl/Web-App-Generator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [ShellJS FAQ](https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs/wiki/FAQ#running-interactive-programs-with-exec):

> ### Running interactive programs with `exec()`
>
> We don't currently support running commands in `exec` which require interactive input. The correct workaround is to use the native `child_process` module:
>
> ```
> child_process.execFileSync(commandName, [arg1, arg2, ...], {stdio: 'inherit'});
> ```
>
> Using `npm init` as an example:
>
> ```
> child_process.execFileSync('npm', ['init'], {stdio: 'inherit'});
> ```

Comment: I missed that when I was reading through the faqs.  Thanks for pointing it out.  `child_process` worked great.